# Atmosphere - Need to modify ws URL before connection

Tags: atmosphere, atmosphere.js

I need to modify the **ws** url before it establishes a websocket connection.

I'm using `@ManagedService` in the server code and subscribing from client side using `$.atmosphere.subscribe(request)`.

I've the following setup:

`Cyberoam firewall --> Apache httpd(mod_proxy_ajp,mod_jk for load balancing) --> Glassfish`

```
Primary Transport --> WebSocket
Fallback Transport --> long-polling
```

**Problem I'm facing:**
The Cyberoam firewall is having a limitation (in WAF) that the max characters in GET URL cannot exceeds **50 chars**. But when I hit the subscribe in atmosphere, it is constructing the URL with all the `X-Atmosphere-..` params along with it.

For e.g `ws://localhost:8080/chat?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=5ebed4c5-0b90-4166-88b2-9f273719ab75&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.2.1-jquery&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&Content-Type=application/json&X-atmo-protocol=true")` which clearly exceeds the allowable limits.

I just need to know whether I can somehow construct the URL in my server code appending all the necessary headers and params before it connects?

Yes, I have set the `attachHeadersAsQueryString:false` while making the initial request, and obviously it doesn't connect with missing headers information while doing a WebSocket connection.

Any suggestions/thoughts would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use request.attachHeadersAsQueryString = false so mo query string will be passed. You may need to upgrade to the latest version of Javascript

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-javascript

-- Jeanfrancois (Atmosphere's lead)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @jfarcand. I'll try the latest version right away and let you know if that works out.

Comment: It is working now. Thanks for your help. The issue was with atmosphere.js